# Alguien sabe porque me sale el siguiente error: 'Pila' object has no attribute 'pila'

Tags: python

Estaba tratando de hacer una búsqueda por amplitud de acuerdo a algunos ejemplos del maestro, pero en la parte de la clase Pila, me da error. No se porque me da error sinceramente ya probé algunas cosas que vi en internet, incluso de aquí, pero no ha funcionado, soy nuevo en el lenguaje le pregunte a mi maestro pero literal solo me dio la traducción del error y ya :(

```
class Pila(object):
    def _init_(self):
        self.pila = []
    def push(self, e):
        #self.pila.append(e)
        self.pila.append(e)
        return 0
    def pop(self):
        u=self.pila[-1]
        lt=self.pila[:-1]
        self.pila=lt
        return u

def verificarP(obj, pila):
    for i in pila.pila:
        if i == obj:
            return 1


grafo= {
'Odarea':['Zerind', 'Sibiu'],
'Zerind': ['Arad','Odarea'], 
'Arad': ['Zerind', 'Timisoara', 'Sibiu'], 
'Sibiu':['Odarea', 'Arad','Farara','Rimnicu_Vileea'],
'Timisoara': ['Arad','Lugoj'],
'Rimnicu_Vileea':['Sibiu','Craiova','Pitesti'],
'Lugoj':['Timisoara', 'Mehadia'],
'Mehadia':['Lugoj','Dobreta'], 'Dobreta':['Mehadia', 'Craiova'], 
'Craiova':['Dobreta','Rimnicu_Vileea','Pitesti'],
'Pitesti':['Rimnicu_Vileea','Craiova','Bucharest'],
'Farara':['Sibiu','Bucharest'],
'Bucharest':['Farara','Pitesti','Giurgui','Urzieeni'],
'Giurgui':['Bucharest'],
'Urzieeni':['Bucharest','Hirsova'],
'Hirsova':['Eforie', 'Vaslui'],
'Eforie':['Hirsova'],
'Vaslui':['Hirsova','Iasi'],
'Iasi':['Vaslui','Neamt'],
'Neamt':['Iasi']
}
```

Mi funcion, aun no se si funciona, pero no me deja continuar el problema de la pila.

```
def BusquedaAmplitud():
    obj= 'Bucharest'
    ini= 'Arad'
    c=0
    p=Pila()
    p.push(ini)
    #l=0
    #ml=0
    #x=3
    while(c==0):
        ul = p.pop()
        if ul != obj:
            p.push(ul)
        c=verificarP(obj,p)
        if c==0:
            print (ul)
        if c==1:
            print(p.pila)
```

Este es el main
#--------------------- MAIN ----------------------------
print("------------ Grafo ------------\n")

```
for key, grafo in grafo.items():
    print (key, '-->', grafo)

BusquedaAmplitud()
```

Answer (score 0):

El método de la clase debería ser `__init__`. Nota que son dos guiones bajos a cada lado.